# Apache ant shows me wrong version of Java which is not even installed on my system when trying to build openfire 3.10.2

Tags: java, ant, openfire, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to compile openfire server 3.10.2 using source cloned from git clone https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire.git. As the title explains that something is wrong with my ANT installation. System details are as follows
OS: Ubuntu 10.04 x64
JDK: /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_40 means version is 1.8.0
Apache Ant: 1.8.0

I modified my build file to display version of java used by ANT and used by system. Here's what i added in my build.xml file

```
<echo>Java Version via Ant: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
<echo>Java Version System Prop: ${java.version}</echo>
```

When build is performed then output of above lines is

```
[echo] Java Version via Ant: 1.6
[echo] Java Version System Prop: 1.8.0_40
```

Which clearly shows that ant is not using correct version of Java.

## More Information:

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

>echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/

>echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40
```

So, at this point I am hopeless to know what's wrong with my Apache ANT installation. Ant shall show 1.8.0 instead of 1.6 so that I can compile openfire. Please help me out here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ant version is too old for Java 8. `ant.java.version` is showing 1.6 simply because it's the latest Java version supported by Ant 1.8.0. Try to upgrade Ant to the latest version.